# Distribution of Y, which is Poisson with mean 1 minus 1. How do we derive the Expectation and Variance?

Tags: probability, asymptotics, poisson-distribution, random-walk

My question is about the following statement:

*Consider a random walk whose step size has distribution Y, which is Poisson with mean 1 minus 1. Asymptotically the critical items are that Y has zero expectation and unit variance.*

I am a little confused as to why the expectation and variance differ for this Poisson distribution. I assume this has to do with the statement " *Asymptotically the critical items are* ". Can someone point me in the right direction how to derive this?

Comment: I wondered about "mean 1 minus 1"!  Isn't that just "mean 0"?  But you need a comma-  "Poisson with mean 1, minus 1".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are subtracting $1$ from the Poisson distribution. We have a random variable $\mathbf X \sim \text{Poisson}(1)$, with mean $1$ and variance $1$; then, we define $\mathbf Y = \mathbf X - 1$, which has mean $0$ and variance $1$.

The next statement is just saying that to understand the asymptotic behavior of the random walk, the mean and variance of $\mathbf Y$ are all that we need to know.